# Accessing PHP Value through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Ok so what I'm basically trying to do is sending a form which contains a password (predefined, no DB) through AJAX. In my php file I check the input and I try to return true or false to my JS, but this part fails as I can't manage to access the value. Here is my code:

**ajaxRequest.js**

```
// Variable to hold request
var request;

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$(".lockForm").submit(function(event){

// Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
event.preventDefault();

// Abort any pending request
if (request) {
    request.abort();
}
// setup some local variables
var $form = $(this);

// Let's select and cache all the fields
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

// Serialize the data in the form
var serializedData = $form.serialize();

// Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
// Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
// Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);

// Fire off the request to /form.php
request = $.ajax({
    url: "assets/php/lockscreen.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.status);
    }
});

// Callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// Callback handler that will be called regardless
// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    // Reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});

});
```

**lockscreen.php**

```
<?php


// You can access the values posted by jQuery.ajax
// through the global variable $_POST, like this:
$pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : null;
$response = false;

function CheckInput($pass){

if($pass == "SPV" || $pass == "TEACHERS"){
    $response = true;
    $responseLock['status'] = 'true';
    echo json_encode($responseLock);
} else {
    $response = false;
    $responseLock['status'] = 'true';
    echo json_encode($responseLock);
}

}

?>
```

So far I tried changing the dataType to JSON, but then I got an unexpected end of input error. If I leave it 'text', whenever I try to access the value, I get "undefined". If I only display the console.log, without trying to access any value, I get a success message. I have no idea why though.

Comment: You get "undefined" *where* exactly when you try to access *what* exactly?

Comment: Do you ever call the `CheckInput` function?

Comment: Debug  and past the log form console

Comment: @fredrik That’s the problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

call your **`CheckInput`** function:

```
<?php
$pass     = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : null;
$response = false;

function CheckInput($pass) {
    if($pass == "SPV" || $pass == "TEACHERS"){
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }

    return array('status' => $result);
}

echo json_encode(CheckInput($pass));
?>
```